# Android Studio System Health Warning

Tags: android-studio, configuration, java-8, ubuntu-14.04

I work with Android Studio in Ubuntu 14.04

When I open my Android Studio I've got the next warning:

[image]

So I proceed to update my Java Plaform from OpenJDK to JDK Oracle

I have downloaded the JDK Oracle and copy in /user/lib/jvm/ and then I follow the next instrucctions to install it https://askubuntu.com/questions/56104/how-can-i-install-sun-oracles-proprietary-java-jdk-6-7-8-or-jre/55960#55960

I check my new Java version and I can see that I have the new version:

[image]

I open my Android Version and I can see the warning another time. So, I go to File > Project Structure > SDK Location and change the JDK location to my new JDK Location:

[image]

Then, I close my Android Studio, open again and the Android Studio warning still there.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably way too late to the party, but for anyone else looking:

Based on this post on [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/534378/android-studo-showing-openjdk-shows-intermittent-performance-and-ui-issues) you need to set the default JVM for Java apps. This *isn't* the same as setting which JDK your Android Studio project uses. This is the virtual machine that the actual Android Studio runs from.

Check what `sudo update-alternatives --config java` prints out for you as the default JVM for your system then change it to the one you desire.

Answer (score 1):

On Linux, Android Studio is run by a shell script located at:

```
<Android Studio location>/bin/studio.sh
```

Along the way, it decides which JDK Android Studio uses.  By setting environment variables you can influence how it chooses.

In your ~/.profile file, add a line like so...

```
export STUDIO_JDK="/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_45"
```

Logout and back in, and try running Android Studio again.  It should now be running using the JDK that you expect.